# Counts of two fields in different table with grouping not working

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

I have three table a, b and c in mysql. a has events, b has ticket categories for each event of a, and c has tickets each of b. So a pure relational datbase. What i'm trying to find out is the count of total ticket categories and total tickets each of the event a has.

I had tried like this:

```
SELECT a. * , COUNT( b.at_id ) AS totTktCat, COUNT( c.bt_id ) AS totTkts
FROM a_table a
JOIN b_table b
USING ( at_id ) 
JOIN c_table c
USING ( bt_id ) 
GROUP BY a.at_id
```

but no luck, the totals are wrong.
A little help from the mysql gurus will help.
I have added an sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec8b0/1.
I'm getting total like this

```
at_id   at_cat  at_event    totTktCat   totTkts
1       1       aevent1     6           6
2       2       aevent2     2           2
```

which is wrong.

#### MY expected output is

```
at_id at_cat at_event COUNT(bt_ticktgrp) COUNT(ct_tickets)
2     2      aevent2  2                  4
```

For the sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ebc9ea6

Comment: `GROUP BY a.at_id,c.bt_id`

Comment: i wanted the total of ticket group and total tickets for each event.

Comment: @Alex then the events are repeating.

Comment: what is `at_cat` here???is there any need of this parameter when you have `at_id` with you??

Comment: @Abbas at_cat is the event category like baseball, basketball, etc. its the actual key. I'm grouping or filtering all according to events.

Comment: sorry but let me clear one thing i.e you are referring some another table for categories also??so the actual hierarchy is  `category->event->group->tickets` ???am i correct???

Comment: @Abbas Yes query can be:SELECT a. * , COUNT( b.at_id ) AS totTktCat, COUNT( c.bt_id ) AS totTkts
FROM a_table a
JOIN b_table b
USING ( at_id ) 
JOIN c_table c
USING ( bt_id ) 
GROUP BY a.at_id where a.at_cat in (1,2)

Comment: so can you let me know your expected output as per the table given in your sql fiddle as i need to clear it out before i post anything....  try to give expected one by editing your question...

Comment: @Abbas please see the edits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100664/discussion-between-abbas-and-plum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your given description, i have written query like this..

```
SELECT a.at_id,a.at_cat,a.at_event,count(*) as bt_ticktgrp,(SELECT count(*) FROM `b_table` b JOIN `c_table` c ON c.bt_id=b.bt_id where b.at_id=a.at_id) as ct_tickets  FROM `a_table` a JOIN `b_table` b
ON a.at_id=b.at_id
GROUP BY a.at_cat;
```

Here i have grouped outer one with `table a` and inner one with `table c` by mapping it with `table b`.

i.e With each id of `table a` it joins `table b` and `table c`.

Hope this solves your query.